# Very large unit test execution time in Sonar

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, sonarqube, execution-time

I am investigating the unit test time execution in Sonar, and there are very big differences between the tests run from maven and the tests run from Sonar.

For example, for a single Java test class I get:

- just maven: 1.5 sec
- maven with cobertura: 5.7 sec
- sonar: 16 sec

Why is the difference between maven and Sonar so big?
What other instrumentation does Sonar make that adds 10 sec to the execution time?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Sonar uses JaCoCo. I personally reconciled with the fact that tests take a lot of time under sonar, so we run sonar as a part of nightly build only while regular tests are running after each SVN commit.

I am sorry if my answer does not satisfy you...

Comment: Yes, it's best to run Sonar once a day (during a nightly build for instance) and not at every CI build.